# Elasticsearch output -- how to remove heading on Java calls

Tags: java, elasticsearch, cygwin

I'm running `Elasticsearch` commands from within Java, using `Process` and `ProcessBuilder`, on Windows:

```
new ProcessBuilder(command);
```

`command` here is the array of commands:

```
"C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\curl", "-XGET", "'"+ES_BASE_URL+"index2/_search?pretty'"
```

The output is fine-- except that the following is prepended to the Cygwin output, i.e. the output i get from Cygwin when i run it directly on a Cygwin terminal:

> % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
>                                    Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
>
> 0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
>   100   796  100   796    0     0  27298      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 31840

How to avoid this so that i get bare JSon result, the result i get from Cygwin?

Comment: You could remove it by calling header.detachNode after the getSOAPHeader call.

Comment: @user7790438 can you be more specific? i'm not using SOAP. i'm calling an OS command to invoke Cygwin directly from within Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curl -s -XGET

should suppress meter. ( You can also reduce it to just a progress bar instead of those numbers by curl -# )

From curl manual:

> -#, --progress-bar
>                 Make curl display progress as a simple progress bar instead of the standard, more informational, meter.
>
> -s, --silent
>                 Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages.  Makes Curl mute. It will still output the data you ask for,
>   potentially
>                 even to the terminal/stdout unless you redirect it.